# Translate Service (@ngx-translate/core) isn't translating the labels in ionic2 project when run on device

Tags: angular, ionic2, ngx-translate

The application uses @ngx-translate/core --- TranslateService to translate the labels in the ionic2 app to another language, which seems to work fine when run as web view or in the ionic lab.
however, when the same app is built and run into an ios device the labels are not loaded. 
eg : {{LOGIN.USERNAME}} should be displayed as username from the en.json file. but being shown as LOGIN.USERNAME in the app.

what could be the issue?

Comment: Are you using the `WKWebView`?

Comment: No, we are running it on the web using general serve command and deploying it on an ios device to check the device view.
I'm unaware of WKWebView.

Comment: Please check in the `config.xml` file if you find the word `WKWebView` (when running the app on an iOS device you're using either `UIWebView` or `WKWebView`). If you find the word `WKWebView` I know how you can fix the issue...

Comment: i could find this in the xml file:
<preference name="UIWebViewBounce" value="false" />